# How to write function that will work correctly if should run concurrently?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I have a table *some_table(id integer, x integer)*
How to write function that will work correctly if should run concurrently?
Here my current version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION actualize_table(
  IN  p_id INTEGER,
  IN  p_x  INTEGER,
  OUT p_created BOOLEAN
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$

BEGIN

  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE id = p_id FOR SHARE) THEN
      p_created = FALSE;
  ELSE
      p_created = TRUE;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO some_table (id) VALUES (p_id) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET x = p_x;

END;
$BODY$;
```

But it seems, that this function will not work correctly if row not exists, so there will no lock on select.
I mean, will `FOR SHARE` work correctly on that case?
What do you think?

Comment: Well if the row does not exist it can't be locked, there is not much you can do about that. In any case you have that covered in the `ELSE` clause. It would be helpful to know what the condition is that you are protecting against?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I want to protect against the case when 2 parallel transactions can see that there is no row with id = p_id, so p_created = TRUE for both transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from postgresql documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html

> UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements set FOUND true if at least one
> row is affected, false if no row is affected.

```
 INSERT INTO some_table (id)
  VALUES (p_id)
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
  IF FOUND THEN
      p_created = TRUE;
  ELSE
      p_created = FALSE;
  END IF;
```